# How to unit test a Scala 3 macro?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

I am trying to unit test the following, simplified, macro (by comparing the emitted expressions):

```scala
trait MyOutput {
  def speak(): Unit
}

inline def myMacro(): MyOutput = ${ myMacroImpl() }

def myMacroImpl()(using Quotes): Expr[MyOutput] = {
  '{
    new MyOutput {
      def speak(): Unit = {
        println("Hello World")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the following

```
inline private def testMacro[A](inline generated: A, expected: A): A = {
  ${ testMacroExpr('generated, 'expected) }
}

def testMacroExpr[A](generated: Expr[A], expected: Expr[A])(using Quotes): Expr[A] = {
  import quotes.reflect._

  if (generated != expected) {
    report.throwError("BOOM")
  }
}

// main.scala
@main def hello() = {
  testMacro(
    myMacro(),
    new MyOutput {
      def speak(): Unit = {
        println("Hello World")
      }
    }
  )
}
```

But the comparison always returns `false`. Also, I remarked `expected.asTerm.toString()` returns `Inlined(EmptyTree,List(),Ident(expected$proxy1))`.

I also tried:

- using functions defined on `Expr` and `Quotes`, such as [matches](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/8d9542cf3b90a5ae0b0a0a85062fa7a0b66277d2/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala#L41)
- comparing `generated.show` and `expected.asTerm.underlying.show`

Can someone point me to solution please?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to test the compiler. I would rather use the macro and assert its output in a more specific way.

Comment: Yes of course, is it the case on my side to test the behaviour. But as the macro can be fairly complex I wanted to ensure its content is correct.

Comment: Why is `generated` `inline` but `expected` not `inline`? Their trees will be too different in such case. Why not to make both of them `inline`?

Comment: You shouldn't expect that the trees will be identical. The tree of `myMacro` will keep the information that it is obtained from a macro expansion while the other won't. Also there will be differences in name resolving: `<root>.scala.Unit` vs. `scala.Unit`, `java.lang.Object` vs. `lang.Object`, `<root>.<empty>.App$.MyOutput` vs. `<empty>.App.MyOutput`.